# Remove rows based on the rownames in list

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation

I have a list and I want to remove all the rows with  `"Volvo 142E"` from `data`. any help will be appriciated.

```
data("mtcars")
rownames(mtcars)
data <- list(mtcars ,mtcars, mtcars, mtcars);data

out1 <- NULL
for(i in seq_along(data)) {
  out1[[i]] <- data[[i]][!(rownames(data[[i]]) %in% data[[i]] == "Volvo 142E" ), ]
}
out1
```

many thanks in advance

Comment: Try `lapply(data, function(i){rownames(i) <- NULL; i})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lapply` to iterate over list and then subset the rows :

```
lapply(data,function(x) x[rownames(x) != "Volvo 142E", ])
```

Equivalent "tidy" option would be :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(data, ~.x %>% filter(rownames(.) != "Volvo 142E"))
```

Comment: out1 <- NULL
for(i in seq_along(data)) {
   out1[[i]] <- data[[i]][rownames(data[[i]]) != "Volvo 142E", ]
}
out1